# How can I find loading adress of eCos firmware

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware

From:https://www.tendacn.com/en/download/detail-3482.html
[image]

Im trying to find loading address (entry point of my program) for this binary, which is part off this firmware. Im trying to load it inside of IDA, how can I correctly load it, how to find entry point address?
binwalk's output:

Comment: have you tried the address printed by binwalk?

Comment: yes ,it's not loading address.and i have tried to use uart address

Comment: what is the output from? it doesn't seem to match the linked file

Comment: They're the same system, slightly different(only size).They all need to be found the loading address.